# Restoring an iPhone to its default state regarding allowing installation of custom applications

Tags: mobile-device-management, mdm

Someone installed a custom app store on my iPhone to do an experiment, the experiment is done and I want to remove this app store and whatever related to it.

The app store can install apps on my iPhone, as far as I know it should have an entry for it in Settings -> General -> Device Management but I can't see anything so it's making me uncomfortable. I can uninstall this app store but as soon as I reinstall it I can still install apps with it without having an entry in Device Management so I think something is remaining on my device which allows this app store to install apps. I want to completely get rid of it. Any ideas?

Comment: You iPhone "may" have been Jailbroken. What is the version of iOS running on it? Can you share a screenshot of the "the app store"? Are you looking to restore your iPhone to factory state?

Comment: I doubt if it's Jailbroken, I don't have it installed now and I want to avoid installing it again. My iOS is 13.3. If I reset my iPhone to factory state can I restore all my current applications and settings from a backup in iCloud?